# 500 error cloudpage form to Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm getting a 500 error when adding the CampaignMember bit in the code so

```
SET @CampaignMember = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
     "CampaignId", "7011t0000009Cl1",
     "ContactId", @contactId,
     "Status", "Sent"
      )
```

If I take off that bit it works perfectly fine. I can't see any reason why I'm getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

  /* check if contact already exists */
  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
    "Contact",
    "Id,Email",
    "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
  )

  /* get contact id if contact exists */
  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
    SET @contactId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")

    /* update existing contact */
    SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Contact", @contactId,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname")
    )
  ENDIF
  
 SET @CampaignMember = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
 "CampaignId", "7011t0000009Cl1",
 "ContactId", @contactId,
 "Status", "Sent"
  )  


  /* check if lead already exists */
  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead",
   "Id,Email",
   "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
   )
  
  /* get lead id if lead exists */
  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @leadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")
  
  /* update existing lead */
  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Lead", @leadId,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Title", RequestParameter("title"),
      "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
      "Industry", RequestParameter("industry")
     )
           
  ELSE
   /* create a new lead */
  SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Lead", 6,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Title", RequestParameter("title"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
        "Industry", RequestParameter("industry")
       )       
   
  ENDIF       


 add lead to a campaign
SET @CampaignMember = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
     "CampaignId", "7011t0000009Cl1",
     "LeadId", @leadId,
     "Status", "Sent"
      )  
     

  
]%% 
<h2>Thank you for submitting the form, you will get a confirmation email shortly.</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

<table style="padding: 20px;">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
        <label>First name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" required=""><br>
        <label>Last name: </label><input type="text" name="lastname" required=""><br>
        <label>Title: </label><input type="text" name="title" required=""><br>
        <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="company" required=""><br>
        <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required=""><br>
        <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some comment tags -- `/*` and `*/` -- around `add lead to a campaign`.

Are you supplying all of the required fields and values for creating a CampaignMember record?  It's either that or a datatype mismatch.

Does `@leadId` have a value?

Comment: I missed the comment tags when I pasted the code but I have them in my code. Yes, leadId have a value